# CLLocation returning (null) coordinates

Tags: ios, objective-c, exif, cllocation

Below is code for my CLLocationManagerDelegate. I call the delegate methods using:

```
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

The delegate methods:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                           initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    //get current location of phone:
    if (newLocation != nil) {
        _m.longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        _m.latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
        _m.timestamp = newLocation.timestamp;
        NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    }
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

}
```

When I call the didUpdateToLocation method, I've verified through debugging that newLocation is not nil. _m is an object declared in my header, and is not nil either. The same is true for locationManager. However, when I try to set _m.latitude etc. and NSLog them, they all show up as (null). The didUpdateToLocation NSLog results in a line like this:

didUpdateToLocation: <+47.64312748,-122.12163262> +/- 65.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 7/15/14, 9:26:07 AM Pacific Daylight Time

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: What is `_m`?  What shows up as `(null)`?  You should be using `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:`  The method you're using has been deprecated since iOS 6.0.

Comment: _m is an object that contains latitude, longitude, and timestamp as NSString, NSString, and NSDate, respectively.

Comment: How are you logging the value? try NSLog(@"Cord: %.f", cord);

Comment: Using your NSLog statement, I get 0 for the latitude and 48 for the longitude.

Comment: Try to use @"%.8lf" instead of @"%.8f".

Comment: I changed it to @"%@" since lat and long are stored as strings, and I got normal coordinates. However, when I NSLog them in the same way outside of the delegate method, I get (null).

Comment: Just fyi: the last line in didUpdateToLocation `CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;` has no real effect because `currentLocation` is a local variable and then the method ends and `currentLocation` is gone.

Comment: Also, the `_m` variable seems unnecessary since `locationManager.location` will give you the same thing even outside the delegate method (just need to make sure it's not `nil` before using it).

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct. So probably you get null in logs because `_m == nil`.

Comment: _m == nil evaluates to 0.